# Como ingresar datos flotantes en formato HTML en ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

estoy intentando ingresar datos flotantes en un campo numérico pero no se guardan en la base de datos y no se porque. En la siguiente imagen, el campo altura (que es el campo flotante) no ingresa ningún dato.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta imagen del diseño, se muestra claramente que el dato lo tengo definido como float.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de guardar los datos, no se almacena el dato de altura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Guardar.cshtml

```
***
```

@model Certamen_Jeremy_Fernandez.Models.Datos1

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Guardar";
}

<h2>Guardar</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Nuevo", "Datos1", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class ="form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Datos1</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.correo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.correo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.correo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.contrasena, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.contrasena, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "password" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.contrasena, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.altura, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.altura, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @step = "0.01", @value = "5.00"} })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.altura, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fecha, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "datetime-local"} })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fecha, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <font color="green">@ViewBag.mensaje</font>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Es posible obtener el modelo empleado, para observar la especificación de la propiedad "altura".?
Si empleas librerias como "DataAnnotations" quizas falta especificar en la propiedad

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$")]
[Range(0, 9999999999999999.99)]
public decimal Altura{ get; set; }
```